# Oracle query to get all entries based on sum of two column value

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Let's assume I have the below table in my Oracle db:

```
ID  foo  bar
1   100  1
2   50   1
3   75   1
4   200  1
```

I want to create an SQL query to return those rows for which the sum of foo + bar < 100. So in this I should get rows 2 and 3 back, since for row 2, (50 + 1) <100 and also for row 3, (75 + 1) < 100.

I looked at the SUM operator but that will do a summation for all the rows for the column which is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE foo + bar <100;
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum` sums an expression across multiple lines. To add values within a row, you could just use the arithmetic `+` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  foo + bar < 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for amusement, a few other options.

A simple, *negation* one:

```
SQL> with test (id, foo, bar) as
  2  (select 1, 100, 1 from dual union
  3   select 2, 50,  1 from dual union
  4   select 3, 75,  1 from dual union
  5   select 4, 200, 1 from dual
  6  )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where not (foo + bar) >= 100
 10  order by id;

        ID        FOO        BAR
---------- ---------- ----------
         2         50          1
         3         75          1

SQL>
```

Or

```
select *
from test
where (foo + bar) / 100 < 1;
```

A little bit *more typing* which covers your

> I looked at the SUM operator ...

intention (though, SUM is a function, not an operator):

```
SQL> with test (id, foo, bar) as
  2  (select 1, 100, 1 from dual union
  3   select 2, 50,  1 from dual union
  4   select 3, 75,  1 from dual union
  5   select 4, 200, 1 from dual
  6  ),
  7  all_in_1 as
  8  (select id, foo foobar from test
  9   union all
 10   select id, bar from test
 11  )
 12  select t.id, t.foo, t.bar
 13  from test t
 14  where t.id in (select a.id
 15                 from all_in_1 a
 16                 group by a.id
 17                 having sum(a.foobar) < 100
 18                )
 19  order by t.id;

        ID        FOO        BAR
---------- ---------- ----------
         2         50          1
         3         75          1

SQL>
```

There certainly are some more nice *tricks* people - who are way better in mathematics than me - might discover.